# How to solve "No cameras rendering" in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container, game-engine, game-development

I am entirely new to Unity. I have a task to work with a tool in Unity. I'm not sure the "Game" is where I should work or the "Scene"? this is how my "Game" tab looks like, but I saw animations in the "Scene" tab. for changing parameters of animation, I should come back to the "Game" tab to change and again go to the "Scene" tab to see the result. I think something is wrong, and I should see the animation in the "Game" tab. Am I right?
It was confusing for me to explain my problem cause I have no idea!
[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of hierarchy may helps us to clarify the problem

Comment: Add a Camera to your scene?

Answer (score 2):

It's very confusing what is happening in your Unity scene.
I assume either you have a disabled camera object or no camera at all.

Search the hierarchy for a MainCamera object and enable it. The game view is rendered from cameras in the application. If you cannot find a camera gameobject, try adding a camera (Gameobject>Camera). If you could find a camera gameobject, you should also check it's Camera component has target display set to Display 1.

Answer (score 2):

In the Scene View at the top left, you can click 2D View. Then you can select the canvas in the hierarchy and press "F", while your mouse is over the scene view, to focus it there. In the end, you should be able to see the canvas in the scene view just as you can in the game view.

In fact, you don't need a camera in the scene to render UI elements, which is quite confusing. So if you don't need to solve the "no camera rendering" problem, as long as there are no 3D objects you want to draw. Keep in mind that you will probably need to manually place an audio listener if you want to hear something at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In your hierarchy window search box write this :

> t:Camera

And see if any will show up. The camera needs to be enabled if there is one present. If there is none, then you need to create one from **GameObjects -> Camera**.

Answer (score 0):

As above answers indicate, there is a missing Camera object. Please keep in mind also that a disabled parent object will affect child objects. This was my case, my Camera object was a child object for a XR Ring object which was disabled and I was getting the "No Cameras rendering" message.